# Visual Basic Or Operator

Tags: vbscript

I have some vb scripts that searches and replaces text in a html page.
It looks like this:-

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, "<span>OK</span><!--test-->" , "<span class=""down"">Down</span><!--test-->") 


Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

This works great if I have just one string of text to replace.
However, I need the script to change the following as well.
This:-

```
<span class=""under-investigation"">Under investigation</span><!--test-->
```

to this:-

```
<span class=""down"">Down</span><!--test-->
```

It should be 'Either' 'Or' though.  If the string says 'OK', then put it to 'down', If the string says 'Under Investigation' then put it to 'down'.
Does anyone know how I could put an Or function in there to say replace 'OK' to 'Down' OR replace 'Under Investigation' to 'Down'?

Difficult to word what I want, sorry if I'm unclear.  Any questions welcome!

many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a second `Replace` instruction?

```
strNewText = Replace(strText, "<span>OK</span><!--test-->" , "<span class=""down"">Down</span><!--test-->")
strNewText = Replace(strNewText, "<span class=""under-investigation"">Under investigation</span><!--test-->" , "<span class=""down"">Down</span><!--test-->")
```

Or do something like this:

```
If InStr(strText, "<span>OK</span><!--test-->") > 0 Then
  strNewText = Replace(strText, "<span>OK</span><!--test-->" , "<span class=""down"">Down</span><!--test-->")
Else
  strNewText = Replace(strText, "<span class=""under-investigation"">Under investigation</span><!--test-->" , "<span class=""down"">Down</span><!--test-->")
End If
```